# Generating Classical Groups over Finite Local Rings

Tags: algebraic-groups, finite-groups

I am interested in classical groups (in particular $SL_n$, $Sp_{2n}$, $SO_n^{+}$) over finite
rings of the form $$R_k=\mathbb{F}_q[t]/(t^k)$$ for some prime power $q$ (where $q$ is odd in the 
orthogonal case) and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Over a finite field, the maximal subgroups of the 
classical groups are known, and so it is for example known that any two semisimple elements of 
orders $q^n+1$ and $q^n-1$ generate the group $Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ (and similar results for 
the other classical groups). I am wondering whether 
it is true that any two semisimple elements of orders $q^{n(k-1)}(q^n+1)$ and $q^{n(k-1)}(q^n-1)$ generate 
$Sp_{2n}(R_k)$. Is anyting like this known? Are there lists of maximal subgroups for classical
groups over finite rings? I would also be interested in similar results over $\mathbb{Z}_p/(p^k)$.

EDIT:  The answer to the question as asked is usually [vacuously yes](https://mathoverflow.net/a/19077/2383).  Instead, [asm](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4819/asm) meant actually to ask about the group generated by two *tori* (not just two semisimple elements) of the specified orders, specifically they said (in a now deleted answer):

"I misphrased my question. What I meant to ask is whether any two maximal tori of order $q^{n(k-1)}(q^n+1)$ and $q^{n(k-1)}(q^n-1)$ generate $Sp_{2n}(R_k)$. Of course these tori are far from cyclic. I guess my head was still in the cyclic case $Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$."

Comment: I fixed a problem with your LaTeX caused by jSMath (there was nothing wrong with your LaTeX specifically though, just a bug.

Comment: There are definitely some people who have studied classical groups
over commutative rings including local rings, for example N.A.
Vavilov (St. Petersburg) and his collaborators.    My impression is
that results have been somewhat scattered and fragmentary.   There
are some connections with algebraic K-theory as well.    A creative
literature search using MathSciNet might be useful.   Generation of
the groups has been a standard theme, but I doubt that you will
find definitive results on maximal subgroups for your rings.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **YES** (at least if $n,k \ge 2$), because elements of the orders you prescribe **do not exist**!  The problem is that the orders of elements in the kernel of $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(R_k) \to \operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(R_1) = \operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbf{F}_q)$ are quite small.

Let $A$ and $B$ be your two elements.  I am assuming that by semisimple, you mean in particular that the images of $A$ and $B$ in $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(R_1)$ should be semisimple.  You are requiring $A^{q^n+1}$ and $B^{q^n-1}$ to have order $q^{n(k-1)}$.  By the semisimplicity, these powers would have to be of the form $I+tM$.  But then they are killed by raising to the $q^r$ power already for $r:=n(k-1)-1$, since $q^r \ge 2^{2(k-1)-1} \ge k$ and hence
$$(I+tM)^{q^r} = I + t^{q^r} M^{q^r} = I$$
in $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}(R_k)$.  This contradicts your specifications.